# How Can I Determine a Region, Country, and Continent Based on a City Using Python?

Tags: python

So, I have a list of a bunch of city and state/region combinations (where some cities do not have a paired state/region) and I'd like to use these to fill in country, continent, (and state/region where it's not supplied) information. Where multiple regions would fit, I'm willing to accept any of them, though the biggest one would be best. What's the simplest library for Python that will let me do this?

An example: given "Istanbul," I'd want something like:

`{istanbul, istanbul province, turkey, europe}`

Comment: I think you picked a very good example of the problems related to this kind of simple minded classifications. Are you aware that the Bosphorus strait divides the Istanbul province in two parts: the European side and the Asian side ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Kimvais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180174/kimvais) and [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/lennart-regebro), I've figured out a pretty simple way of doing what I wanted, and I wanted to post the basic steps here for anyone else who has the same problem.

1. Install geopy (http://code.google.com/p/geopy/)
2. Use the following:

   ```
    from geopy import geocoders

    gn = geocoders.Google()
    place, (lat, lng) = gn.geocode("istanbul")
    print place
   ```

This prints: `Istanbul/Istanbul Province, Turkey`, which is awesome and exactly what I wanted (sans the continent part, but that's pretty easy to do on my own with just a list of country/continent combos (yes I'm aware Turkey is in 2 different continents. I'm happy just placing it in one for my purposes since it doesn't matter too much to me).

Comment: How did you map `Turkey` to a continent?

Comment: @MattO'Brien just what I said-- got a list of country -> continent, made it into a dictionary, and just queried against that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library for this at all, really. What you do need is a list of geographic locations. If you don't have that there are geolocation services online you can use, that will do these things for you, accessible via http (and hence urllib). You might need a library to interpret the response, that could be XML, for example.

Comment: Can you give an example of any of those services?

Comment: @Eli: Google maps has one: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/, and Kimvais mentioned Geonames.org http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html can return the type of data you are looking for.

Comment: @Lennart: google geocoding is usable only from google maps, or you are violating their TOS. openstreetmap is much better on this regard, but parsing the results is pure pain.

Comment: @Lennart : from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ : `Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.`

Comment: Other terms of services say completely different things, so I guess that needs to be cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/) interface to [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) might be useful