# Python, Pandas, Geopy: How can I find if a certain location is within the city?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, data-analysis, data-science

I have data for list of schools and I want to find if those schools are located within the city or outside the city.

Head of my dataframe looks like below:
[image]

I referred this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844811/how-can-i-determine-a-region-country-and-continent-based-on-a-city-using-pytho) but it gives me the information like `city,state,country` which I already have. What I am looking for is a straight yes/no in a separate column.

Comment: Do you have their coordinates? Or what do you want the classification of schools to cities depend on?

Comment: @jubins I think you would need some kind of mapping for each city in which depending on the postcode you determine if you consider that within or outside, because it looks to me you are looking for something subjective. From there you can automate the process using the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844811/how-can-i-determine-a-region-country-and-continent-based-on-a-city-using-pytho) you mentioned

Comment: @splinter  No I don't have the coordinates but the post I mentioned in question will give me longitude and latitude. Can I find something from it?

Comment: @VictorGGl For my task I have to answer this question: `Given a region (New England, Great Lakes, Southwest, etc.), what is the probability an academic institution in that region is located in a city?` I can get counts for institutions in region 5, region 4 and so on. But how can I know if city is in that region? I dont have any other data, my dataframe has 7000 rows and 5 columns

Comment: Do you also have coordinates of the regions?

Comment: @splinter my regions are numerical values, I have zipcode for each institution. I don't have any data associating numerical regions with textual.

Comment: regions are numerical values? what does that mean?

Comment: so you will need to find a criterium for `an academic institution in that region is located in a city`. Can you use the zipcode of the institution?