# How can I merge two rows in a pandas dataframe into a one row with a new name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

So I want add two different rows with 5 columns containing integers on top of eachother, and create a new row based on this. Is there a way to add these last 5 columns of each row together, then creat new values in the other columns based on these totals?

Basically I want to turn this:

| idx | area | regimen | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | val_4 | val_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Lima | Black | 78 | 209 | 580 | 18 | 700 |

and this:

| idx | area | regimen | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | val_4 | val_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Pucalpa | Black | 250 | 845 | 1659 | 39 | 2101 |

INTO this:

| idx | area | regimen | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | val_4 | val_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Peru | Black | 328 | 1054 | 2239 | 57 | 2801 |

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what to do with the first three columns; however, you can select the remaining columns with `iloc` and add the two filtered dataframes together. This assumes that the dataframes have the same number of rows. From there, you can get the first 3 columns data from the second dataframe (you could also use the first) with `combine_first`:

```
df3 = df1.iloc[:, 3:] + df2.iloc[:, 3:]
df3.combine_first(df2)
Out[1]: 
      area  idx regimen  val_1  val_2  val_3  val_4  val_5
0  Pucalpa   11   Black    328   1054   2239     57   2801
```

Comment: I followed this line of thinking before and I'm getting NaN values across the board:

5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
11 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

I checked the data type as well and it is Int64

Comment: @EricMinner my guess is that # of rows and therefore indices in both data frames are different, so this wouldn’t work. Can you post more data.

Comment: This is all of the data that I can think of to provide.  I think what could have been an issue is that I put a column for idx in the question that doesn't actually exist in the real filtered dataframes. There's just an autogenerated index there for where I put 5 ,11 and 12 that isn't actually a column. The 5 and 11 are from the original dataframe before filtering. Sorry about that, I wasn't thinking about it.

Comment: @EricMinner aside from any syntax, fundamentally there has to be something in common to bne able to add two rows together. Usually this is a) a common index between two dataframes or b) one or more columns that have something unique in common so that you can add them together. The only thing in common is that the two cities are in Peru. You may need to create a country column that derives the country based on the city . then you can combine the two dataframes with `pd.concat` and `.groupby(sum)` to get the results.

Comment: for getting the country you can do this: `df['area'].apply(lambda x: gn.geocode(x))` fom this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844811/how-can-i-determine-a-region-country-and-continent-based-on-a-city-using-pytho

Comment: Figured out that I just needed to reset the index, then I applied the same iloc method that you laid out and it worked. Thank you so much for your help, let me know if there's anything I can do for you.

Comment: @EricMinner no problem kindly accept the solution. Thank you!